# Apache AuthLDAPURL and ldapsearch

Tags: apache, svn, ldap, openldap

I am trying to correlate what Apache does for the AuthLDAPURL with ldapsearch. I have a setup where I can run an ldapsearch to successfully test a user's credentials, but I cannot seem to translate that to an Apache configuration.

Do you have any ideas on how to emulate what Apache is doing with an LDAP search, or how to create the AuthLDAPURL so it matches the ldapsearch?

This is on Ubuntu 22.04, OpenLDAP (May 12 2022), Apache (2.4.41).

I can do the following ldapsearches to show the user is in the system and the password is correct.

```
ldapsearch -x -LLL -H ldap://testserver -D "cn=admin,dc=testserver" -W -b "ou=people,dc=testserver" -s children "(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=billy))" dn
Enter LDAP Password:
dn: uid=billy,ou=people,dc=testserver

root@testserver:/home/sysadmin# ldapsearch -x -LLL -H ldap://testserver -D "uid=billy,ou=people,dc=testserver" -W -b "dc=testserver" -s children "(objectClass=*)"
Enter LDAP Password:
<prints tree under dc=testserver>
```

Here is my Apache configuration:

```
<Location /svn/>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /var/svn
    SVNListParentPath On
    AuthName 'Please use your Testserver account'
    AuthType Basic
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthLDAPBindDN "cn=admin,dc=testserver"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword "password"
    # Test the user account
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://testserver:389/ou=people,dc=testserver?uid?sub?(ObjectClass=*)"
    require valid-user
</Location>
```

Here is my LDAP configuration:

```
dn: ou=people,dc=testserver
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: people

dn: ou=groups,dc=testserver
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: groups

dn: uid=billy,ou=people,dc=testserver
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
cn: Bill
sn: Belichick
userPassword: {SSHA}pr4TabkZcr/ZAtiHBgL6bF1jvuvIJ6dn
loginShell: /bin/bash
uidNumber: 2001
gidNumber: 2001
homeDirectory: /home/bill

dn: ou=svn,ou=groups,dc=testserver
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: groups

dn: cn=svn_folder_repo1_rw,ou=svn,ou=groups,dc=testserver
objectClass: groupOfNames
cn: svn_folder_repo1_rw
member: uid=billy,ou=people,dc=testserver
```

Finally, the Apache error log reports ...

```
[Thu Aug 11 02:24:04.914162 2022] [auth_basic:error] [pid 4631] [client 192.168.99.1:49323] AH01617: user billy: authentication failure for "/svn/": Password Mismatch
```

*** --- Edit --- ***

I tried with a non user and got the same message.

```
[Thu Aug 11 11:43:13.916494 2022] [auth_basic:error] [pid 619] [client 192.168.99.1:60322] AH01617: user eric: authentication failure for "/svn/": Password Mismatch
```

Comment: I don't see any problem with the specified AuthLDAPURL, it seems to work for Apache to find the user entry "uid=billy,...", but as it says there is "Password Mismatch". Though, to ensure the error message is not misleading, you can try to log in with an uid that doesn't exist in the directory and check the error message.

Comment: Note that the password that is in LDAP was created with slappasswd. Do I need to use any special parameters to match the method that Apache uses? I know there's all kinds of ways to store a password.

Comment: I would assume that the ldap provider automatically matches the password storage scheme it finds during authentication, but I might be wrong. Does the entry of the ldap admin also use SSHA ? If it does and the binding works, then it should be fine. But, since Apache is not specific at all in these error messages, you can try to put a wrong bind password, just to know if you should consider or eliminate the possibility that "Password Mismatch" could _also_ refer to the binding operation (there is no authentication attempt if the binding fails).